# Why are Angular's activated route params of type "any"?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing, angular-router

Just out of curiosity I tried to assign an `ActivatedRoute`'s param to my variable defined to be a number:

```
public id: number;

constructor(public activatedRoute: ActivatedRouter) {}

public ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.take(1).subscribe((params) => {
        this.id = params['id']; // I was expecting to see a warning here
    }
}
```

...and it passed without any warning in my IDE and tslint. So I dug into it and discovered that it emits [Params](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router_state.ts#L126) declared ([here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/shared.ts#L25)) to contain `any` elements:

```
export type Params = {
  [key: string]: any
};
```

And the question is why? AFAIK all the parameters are always strings. Is there a way to say Angular that some of our param should be a `number` or `array` and it will parse it?

Comment: Keep in mind that Angular doesn't do parameter validation, and any type warnings are at compiled time from TypeScript to JavaScript. At run-time `params['id']` will likely be a string. Therefore `any` is valid as you don't know what it is. You should `this.id = parseInt(params['id']);` if you want to ensure a number value.

Comment: Yeah I know, I meant there is no warning in IDE and tslint - I specified it in the question now... I'm not asking what should I do or why it passes since it's kind of obvious. I'm wondering why the decision was made - is there a reason for it or just some lazy developer used already existing type?

Comment: I think it's a bit of both. You'll find `ElementRef` defines the native DOM element as `any` instead of the JavaScript `Element` type or even `Node`. One of the reasons is that Angular can run in environments were there is no browser (like in NodeJS). So I think the general idea is anything coming from outside the domain of Angular has an `any` type. As the team can not guarantee what the type will be.

Comment: So what other type could come from the route path?

Comment: I don't know.... just string.. :)

Comment: @DanielKucal please check https://github.com/smnbbrv/ngx-typed-router . Might be useful